# what‘s the difference between CCTexture2D and CCSpriteFrame?

Tags: cocos2d-x

As we know, there are two ways to create `CCSprite`, using `CCTexture2D` and `CCSpriteFrame`.

what‘s the difference between `CCTexture2D` and `CCSpriteFrame`?

According to [CCTexture2D API](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.3/d7/dfd/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_texture2_d.html#afc07f5610c73ea60853b042464c35c53) and [CCSpriteFrame API](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2.3/d3/d45/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_sprite_frame.html), they can both be created by files.

I can not find the key point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- CCTexture2D is the whole texture. It contains texture info like size, OpenGL texture name, GL program etc;
- CCSpriteFrame is part of texture. It contains CCTexture2D and a rectangle area that we would like to use from texture.

Usually CCSpriteFrame is used with sprite atlases created with 3rd party programs (like [texturepacker](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) or [zwoptex](https://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex/)).

P.S. I advise You to use the 3rd version of Cocos2d-x